# Fill a vector with random numbers

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function in a class I'm writing that is just supposed to fill a vector with random numbers.  For some reason, it only generates the same random number and fills the array with that number, despite using a loop where rand() is called over and over.  I seeded rand with time(0).  I tried placing the seed inside of the loop and it made no difference.  Here's my function.  'array' is actually a vector.

```
void fillArray()
   {
      srand(time(0));

      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
      {
         array.at(i) = rand() % 200;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Did you execute several times? Did you try putting this into the `main` and operate on a `vector` of size `10` to do a trivial test?

Comment: Your question made me look again at my class.  What I was doing was using an overloaded 'at()' function in my class to copy the vector class's at() function.  I declared it as const which was preventing the index from changing.  Removing const made it work correctly.  Thank you!

Comment: @Sabien If you find an answer, [post an answer to your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the state of array. Perhaps, size () is zero when the call of for is done, in which case nothing is written into array. I suggest that you check that first.

Moreover, to perform module 200 is not good for randomness. I copy a snippet from man page for rand():

```
In  Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing (William H.
       Press, Brian P. Flannery, Saul A. Teukolsky, William T. Vetterling; New
       York:  Cambridge University Press, 1992 (2nd ed., p. 277)), the follow-
       ing comments are made:
          "If you want to generate a random integer between 1 and 10,  you
          should always do it by using high-order bits, as in

             j = 1 + (int) (10.0 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));

          and never by anything resembling

             j = 1 + (rand() % 10);

          (which uses lower-order bits)."
```

Answer (score -1):

The code above is apparently correct to fill a vector with random numbers.  The error was coming from this function in my class:

```
int at(int index)
   {
      return array.at(index);
   }
```

It was created to use the vector class's at function, but I originally declared it const which made it return the same index for every loop iteration.

Comment: Declaring `at` as `const` should not cause the problem you described, at least not with the implementation in this answer. The problem was likely elsewhere in your code and you inadvertently fixed it without realizing.